# Formula to calculate cell values based on the symbols in the other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying to calculate the following values in a sheet based on the symbols:

[image]

Is there any way of calculating the result with formulas only?

Comment: Do you want this to work on every mathematical operator, or just those two? Because you could simply have an IF statement along the lines of =IF(B1="+", A1+C1,A1*C1)

Comment: This does not evaluate, but it gets you one step closer, `=INDIRECT("A1")&INDIRECT("B1")&INDIRECT("C1")` will return, `1+2`.

Comment: Yes, but that should be independent from IF condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D1 copied down to suit:

```
=eval
```

where `eval` is a Defined Name set up in D1 that refers to:

```
=EVALUATE(Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1&Sheet1!C1)
```

Hence with `10` in A3, `'/` in B3 and `2` in C3, D3 should return `5`.

Comment: Nice! This is why I love SO - learn something each day. For more information on `=EVALUATE`, see [this article](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html) -- of particular note, `=EVALUATE` can only be used in the definition of a Defined Name.